# Compare SUM of columns to see if equal or greater than threshold value

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sum, compare

I am working on an Excel VBA macro using a Mac. So any code examples would have to work with the Excel for Mac version of Office (Using Office 365)

So what I want to do is:

Compare the Column A "Name" with its corresponding "Grade" values in Column B to the "Grade" values in all the different Columns D, F, and H "Grade" ("Sheet1")

I want to get every combo of the Column A "Name" with the Column C, E, and G "Name" ("Sheet1")

I want to SUM the "Grade" value that is associated to Column A to the "Grade" values in all the possible combo of "Grade" in Columns D, F, and H ("Sheet1")

I want to see if this SUM is greater to or equal to 250

See if the value of the SUM of the "Grade" in Column B, Column D, Column F, and Column H in "Sheet1" is greater than or equal to 250.

If the "Sheet1" "Grade" SUM is greater to or equal to 250 Then:

Copy the Column A "Name" with its corresponding Column B "Grade" of "Sheet1" to the first empty row in Column A and B of "Sheet2"

Copy the Column C "Name" with its corresponding Column D "Grade of "Sheet1" to the first empty row in Column C and D of "Sheet2"

Copy the Column E "Name" with its corresponding Column F "Grade" of "Sheet1" to the first empty row in Column E and F of "Sheet2"

Copy the Column G "Name" with its corresponding Column H "Grade" of "Sheet1" to the first empty row in Column G and H of "Sheet2"

So the Column Headers might be:

Column A "Name"

Column B "Grade"

Column C "Name"

Column D "Grade"

Column E "Name"

Column F "Grade"

Column G "Name"

Column H "Grade"

A sample data set might be:

Fred 80 Jim 80 Bob 50 Bob 40

Sam 60 Jason 10 Fred 85 Anna 97

Jason 90 Anna 78 Anna 65 Sam 99

etc, etc, etc

Results copied to "Sheet2" might be (just some examples, not positive that the math below is correct):

Fred 80 Jim 80 Bob  65 Anna 97

Fred 80 Anna 78 Fred 85 Sam 99

Sam 60 Jim 80 Fred 85 Anna 97

Sam 60 Anna 78 Bob 50 Sam 99

Jason 90 Jim 80 Bob 65 Sam 99

Jason 90 Anna 78 Fred 85 Sam 99

etc, etc, etc

Anything below 250 just wouldn't get copied over to "Sheet2"

Here is my code so far.

```
'<---- **** START OF CODE **** ---->

Sub Test()
  '<---- Declare the variables needed
  Dim wb As Workbook, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet, ws1LastRow, ws2LastRow, i As Long

'<---- Set the value of the variables needed for the loop
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws1LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").EnColumn D(xlUp).row
ws2LastRow= ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").EnColumn D(xlUp).row

'<---- Loop thru the values of Columns B, D, F, and H of Sheet1
For i = 1 To ws1LastRow
  If WorksheetFunction.SUM(ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value, ws1.Cells(i, "D").Value, ws1.Cells(i, "F").Value, ws1.Cells(i, "H").Value) > 250 Then
'<---- If value of the SUM above is > or = to 250, then copy the Column A:H values of Sheet1 to Sheet2
'<---- Ignore if less than 250
'<----- Make sure to compare every (i, 'A') value with every combo of (i, 'C') value, (i, 'E') value,  and (i, 'G') value
    ws1.Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "A")
    ws1.Cells(i, "B").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "B")
    ws1.Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "C")
    ws1.Cells(i, "D").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "D")
    ws1.Cells(i, "E").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "E")
    ws1.Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "F")
    ws1.Cells(i, "G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "G")
    ws1.Cells(i, "H").Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2LastRow, "H"): ws2LastRow = ws2LastRow + 1
  End If
Next i
End Sub

'<---- **** END OF CODE **** ---->
```

Comment: ws1 and ws2 are referencing the exact same sheet --> "Sheet1". Also: you have to add i to ws2LastRow as well - otherwise all copies from ws1 go to the same row on ws2 - for the whole loop.

Comment: Thank you ws2 should have been "Sheet2". That was a typo. ws1 should have been the only "Sheet1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export Data

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportData()
' Needs 'RefColumns'.
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCols As String = "A:H"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sfsCol As Long = 2
    Const sStep As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    ' Other
    Const Minimum As Double = 250
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfrrg As Range: Set sfrrg = sws.Rows(sfRow).Columns(sCols)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefColumns(sfrrg)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count ' same for src and dest
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Range to the Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim cValue As Variant ' Current Value
    Dim sr As Long ' Current Source Row
    Dim c As Long ' Current Column (same for src and dest)
    Dim dr As Long ' Current Destination Row
    Dim Total As Double ' Current Sum
    
    ' Filter the data i.e. write the critical rows to the top
    ' of the Data Array.
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        Total = 0
        For c = sfsCol To cCount Step sStep
            cValue = Data(sr, c)
            If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                Total = Total + cValue
            End If
        Next c
        If Total >= Minimum Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If dr = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no 'Total >= Mininum' found
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination First Cell ('dfCell').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Clear the Destination Clear Range ('dclrg') e.g. 'A2:XFD1048576'.
    With dfCell
        Dim dclrg As Range: Set dclrg = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row, _
            dws.Columns.Count - .Column).Offset(.Row - 1, .Column - 1)
        dclrg.Clear
    End With
    
    ' Write from the Data Array to the Destination Range ('drg').
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    drg.Value = Data

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox dr & " records found.", vbInformation, "Export Data"

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from the first row of a range
'               ('FirstRowRange') through the row range containing
'               the bottom-most non-empty cell in the row's columns.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstRowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' empty range
        Set RefColumns = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

### EDIT

```
Sub ExportCombinedData()
' Needs 'RefColumns'.
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCols As String = "A:H"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sfsCol As Long = 2
    Const sStep As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    ' Other
    Const Minimum As Double = 250
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfrrg As Range: Set sfrrg = sws.Rows(sfRow).Columns(sCols)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefColumns(sfrrg)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count ' same for src and dest
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Range to the Source Array ('sData').
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Define the Destination Array ('dData').
    Dim dData As Variant
    ReDim dData(1 To srCount ^ (cCount / sStep), 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim cVal1 As Variant, cVal2 As Variant, cVal3 As Variant, cVal4 As Variant
    Dim sr1 As Long, sr2 As Long, sr3 As Long, sr4 As Long
    Dim dr As Long ' Current Destination Row
    Dim Total As Double ' Current Sum
    
    ' Filter the data i.e. write the critical rows to the top
    ' of the Destination Array.
    For sr1 = 1 To srCount
        cVal1 = sData(sr1, 2)
        If IsNumeric(cVal1) Then
            For sr2 = 1 To srCount
                cVal2 = sData(sr2, 4)
                If IsNumeric(cVal2) Then
                    For sr3 = 1 To srCount
                        cVal3 = sData(sr3, 6)
                        If IsNumeric(cVal3) Then
                            For sr4 = 1 To srCount
                                cVal4 = sData(sr4, 8)
                                If IsNumeric(cVal4) Then
                                    Total = cVal1 + cVal2 + cVal3 + cVal4
                                    If Total >= Minimum Then
                                        dr = dr + 1
                                        dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr1, 1)
                                        dData(dr, 2) = cVal1
                                        dData(dr, 3) = sData(sr2, 3)
                                        dData(dr, 4) = cVal2
                                        dData(dr, 5) = sData(sr3, 5)
                                        dData(dr, 6) = cVal3
                                        dData(dr, 7) = sData(sr4, 7)
                                        dData(dr, 8) = cVal4
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next sr4
                        End If
                    Next sr3
                End If
            Next sr2
        End If
    Next sr1
    
    If dr = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no 'Total >= Mininum' found
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination First Cell ('dfCell').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Clear the Destination Clear Range ('dclrg') e.g. 'A2:XFD1048576'.
    With dfCell
        Dim dclrg As Range: Set dclrg = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row, _
            dws.Columns.Count - .Column).Offset(.Row - 1, .Column - 1)
        dclrg.Clear
    End With
    
    ' Write teh values from the Destination Array
    ' to the Destination Range ('drg').
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    drg.Value = dData

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox dr & " records found.", vbInformation, "Export Combined Data"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works. You are awesome. The only thing it doesn't do is compare the values of Column B, with the values of Column D, Column F, and Column. What I mean is: Column A, Row 1 is Fred Column B, Row 1 is 80, Column B2, Row 2 is 78, Column B, Row 3 is 80. What I want to do is loop through Column A and test them against the vals in ColB and sum the vals to ColD, F, and H. So maybe adding ColB2 to ColD2 to ColF2 to ColH2 is <> or > to or than 250. But ColB2 + ColD5 + ColF2 + ColH7 does = 250. So include those A, B, C, D, E, F, H vals to "Sheet2". I hope this makes sense

Comment: So ColB2 + ColD2 + ColF2 + ColH2 >= 250 but ColB2 + ColD3 + ColF2 + ColH2 is < 250 but ColB2 + ColD2 + ColF2 + ColH3 > 250 but ColD2 + ColD2 + ColF3 + ColH2 > 250 but ColB2 + ColD3 + ColF2 + ColH3 < 250 but ColB2 + ColD2 + ColF5 + ColH2 > 250 but ColB2 + ColD4 + ColF2 + ColH2 < 250 etc, etc. So a row with values: 1st example above ColA2 ColB2 ColC2 ColD2 ColE2 ColE2 ColF2 ColG3 ColH3 should be Yes and added to "Sheet2", example 2 should be No, example 3 and 4 should be Yes, example 4 is a No, example 5 is a No, example 6 is a Yes, example 7 is a No. etc etc

Comment: It took me a while, but I got it: there are too few results i.e. your sample data is filling in the blanks. I disregarded the sample results due to *not positive that the math below is correct*. I'll try to fix it. It'll take a while.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! The loops are giving me a headache. I understand your code but trying to loop all the rows is beyond me at this point.

Comment: That is awesome!!! It is exactly what I need. Unfortunately my data set is too big and Excel can't handle that many records. I guess there is no way around that. Is there a way to just do some of the rows. Save that result. Do some more rows. Save that result. Etc until all the rows have been looped thru.

Comment: Also, I messed up BIG TIME!!!! I am working on an Excel file with a lot of macros that took me a LONG time to get working properly. I messed that Workbook up but I had a backup so I saved a new version of the Workbook based on the backup Workbook. But the backup was a save from a couple days ago and didn't have like half of the macros I had made. So weeks of work has vanished just like that and I don't think there is any way to recover a previous save!!! Man I messed up big time!!!! But your macro works great and is 100% what I needed :)